# Unable to change height of UIView loaded from nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a view that is loaded from a nib like so:

```
SLSCaseCard* caseCard  = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SLSCaseCard" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

I'm setting it's frame like this:

```
cardFrame = CGRectMake(25,25, caseCard.frame.size.width, 44);
[caseCard setFrame:cardFrame];
[self.view addSubview:caseCard];
```

The  `x` and `y` are changing but the height always remains the same. The view has a size of 224 in the nib, and it stays at that height at runtime.

Comment: might be you are using auto Layout in to you project with xib.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention in the original post, I tried turning AutoLayout on and off on both my nib and my main storyboard, but it didn't help.

Comment: if that view coming from UIView of your xib already then what need to add again??

Comment: @NitinGohel, I'm adding several subviews to my `self.view` dynamically in a loop

Answer (score 2):

Storyboard (or XIB's) generates code for you. And this code is executed in laying out subviews. So if you want to change frame of a view defined in XIB, you should do that after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `layoutSubviews`.

Hence even after you setting the height of the view, your changes are overridden by the code generated by XIB, which overrides the height to the height defined in XIB, in your case 224. Same goes with width.

Comment: I'm loading the views dynamically in a for loop, so I'm trying to change the height as the views are placed.

Comment: If you want dynamic views, do not use XIB's or storyboards. All dynamic view's should be created programmatically. Even if you can get your functionality using XIB, you will eventually find yourself in a pool of errors with constraints and stuff (Unless you are very very comfortable with them). So I suggest you to create the view programmatically.